# NGRX selector : x is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, selector

I'm curious to know why this raises a typerror is there something I'm missing?

```
 export const selectAllUsers = createFeatureSelector<ReadonlyArray<User>>('users');

 export const selectUser = () =>
  createSelector(selectAllUsers, (users) => {
    return users.find(
      (user) =>
        user.name === "Mr.Doe"
    )});
```

Which is very similar to the Book example in the ngrx walktrhough will raise this error in the browser console :

```
 ERROR TypeError: users.find is not a function
    selectUser user.selector.ts:13
    memoizedProjector ngrx-store.mjs:697
```

I will be able to get my user using the selectUser but that boggles me to see this error,
I feel like I'm missing something important in typescript or in store selectors

Tested on firefox and chrome, both under linux

package.json

```
   "@angular/animations": "~13.1.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "~13.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~13.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.1.2",
    "@angular/material": "^13.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~13.1.2",
    "@ngrx/store": "^13.0.2",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^13.0.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"`
```

Edit 1: ERROR TypeError: user.find -> users.find
Edit 2: Nothing but users(players) in the user state, here is a  [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9Af3.png) taken from devtools, the names are different, hence the typo above

Comment: Do you save something else in the users state? Or you directly have an array in that slice of state?? Maybe showing us your state and initialState could be useful

Comment: Also why are you using an anonymous function to wrap the createSelector? Do you need to work that way for any reason? If not would make sense assign direclty the createSelector to the exported variable. Anyways I don't think that this causes the error, is more likely to be something in the state. ( Like storing the users in a users array inside the users state, so you would need to call users.users.find() )

Comment: Try defining the type of users where you are receiving the value

Comment: What is the type of `users`?

Comment: I am receiving my user in through an observeable that I use in a service
`
   Userservice{
    //...
    dealer$: User;
     //...
    someFunction(){
    this.store.select(selectUser()).subscribe(dealer => {
      this.user$ = user;
    } 
}
   //....
The type of users as indicated by vsocde is (parameter) users: readonly User[]

I will try not to use an anonymous function as @Osakr suggests
Sorry for the bad formatting I'm new to Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

@Osakr, @mak15 and @MarteenDev were on the right path : the user state wasn't a pure array of players

[Angular NGRX getting error when dispatching to state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59337830/angular-ngrx-getting-error-when-dispatching-to-state)

I left a reducer that was polluting the state ( I didn't normalize my state at some point)
Don't know why it was working tho, I may have not typed the reducer enough.

This is a first project so I didnt thoroughly did that
https://duncanhunter.gitbook.io/angular-and-ngrx/15.-strongly-type-our-store#2.-add-a-global-state-interface

Anyhow thanks for the help.